# Retrive values and format from - for each loop php

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop

It retrieves entries and displays based on whether there is anything in the field.

However now i need to display all those entries inside a HTML email and it wont let me do the normal way.

I have to generate one $value that outputs all of the loop so i can display the outputted HTML inside my email template.

Any help as to how i can get $allitems to equal something like this:

```
Go to sleep<br/>Wake up<br/>Make your bed
```

This is my code

```
$mydata= json_decode($row['bits']);

for ($x=1; $x<=9; $x++) { 

   $item = "item_$x"; 

   if (isset($mydata->$item) && !empty($mydata->$item)) { 

      $items = '&#10004; '.$mydata->$item; 

   }

   $allitems = explode("<br/>",$items);

}
```

AS i said the code works fine for every other purpose except when i need to collect the data and display inside my html generated email.

Thanks in advance,
jonny

Comment: Perhaps you need to `implode` the $items rather than explode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just put them together into a single string?

```
$str = ""; // Initialise the empty string prior to the for loop.
for(/* code */) {
    $str .= "woop ";
}

echo $str; // woop woop woop if forloop runs three times
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, too easy. Worked a breeze. I had so many tries close to yours but just never thought of adding the dot to the equal which basically creates a new instance if the value. Thats my logic anyway. Thank you so much ;)